# Display 1080p signal on external monitor while laptop screen is 720p

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, display-resolution

I have a HP Pavilion 15-n211sv which has Intel Core i7-4500U with Intel HD Graphics 4400 and a NVIDIA GeForce GT 740M 2GB. My question is, while both the CPU and the GPU supports 1080p the laptop monitor is 720p but I need the extra resolution, so if I buy a Full HD monitor is it possible to display on the laptop's sceeen 720p and on the monitor 1080 on ubuntu through HDMI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is.

If you use the external monitor only (disabling the internal) it should automatically adjust for 1080P; if using both you may need to explicitly set the different resolutions and options.